# SpringPwdDecrypter how to call it from spring framework as per below

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have the following in my beans spring XML configuration file. here they are trying to get the password from a properties file run time and decrypt the password by calling the class "SpringPwdDecrypterUtil" which extends spring FactoryBean.

Question: in properties file where they mentioned with  user and password. But the password is decrypted one which will be decrpted by the below configuration. I want to know how they(existing prod applicaiton) would have generated the password(decrpyted) and  placed in the text file !

bean.xml

```
<property name="password">
            <bean class="com.cname.SpringPwdDecrypterUtil">
                <property name="password">
                  <value>${db.password}</value>
                </property>
            </bean> 
        </property>
```

--SpringPwdDecrypterUtil.java

```
package com.cname;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

public class SpringPwdDecrypterUtil
  implements FactoryBean
{
  private String password = null;
  private String key = null;

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public Object getObject() {
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(this.key)) {
      return CryptoUtils.decryptAndEncodeBase64(this.key, this.password);
    }

    return CryptoUtils.decryptAndEncodeBase64(this.password);
  }

  public Class getObjectType() {
    return String.class;
  }

  public boolean isSingleton() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it protects?

Comment: I don't think it protects. it was designed that way

Comment: i am able to generate the encrypted password using spring. but is there any otherway they might have encyrpted password according to base16 alogrithm?